# How to get a var out of beautifulsoup soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

How would I get the variable out into like a json or any other way 
    to just take out like challenge

```
<html><body><p>var rechallengeState = {
    challenge : '03AHJ_Vuv8ZHJfsjnR3ueIvm89Jfa6oUJ3-kuzA-VcQIaR30A9CZva7lMaBrYlvcGG4cOPCeKXfERQe_u-cMw_8ZVi6CipeJVAYAsrOeBHryWRCMIaMt4V-TQlTgyUA4ndejEgBGUCUw7rwM-ltDr-do8ry-MRv26qQTpS-iCtvONYc6xZBURPEaTo2Nkfq8HJeFA_g6mMLUBG',
    timeout : 1800,
    lang : 'en',
    site : '6LceKe0SAAAAACFIVHolzCVkrGgSfzFASoOmELIc',
    error_message : '',
    programming_error : '',
    is_incorrect : false,
    rtl : false,
    t1 : 'Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9qcy90aC83ZFZqVVRQN3pmYXh1UnMtNFV3Q19KT0dvbHU4LWdXcXhHTlhNMjRoV1VZLmpz',
    t2 : '',
    t3 : '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\x3d\x3d'
};

</p></body></html>
```

This is my Soup from beautifulsoup4. 
   How would I get the variable out into like a json or any other way 
    to just take out like challenge
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Description in code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<html><body><p>var rechallengeState = {
    challenge : '03AHJ_Vuv8ZHJfsjnR3ueIvm89Jfa6oUJ3-kuzA-VcQIaR30A9CZva7lMaBrYlvcGG4cOPCeKXfERQe_u-cMw_8ZVi6CipeJVAYAsrOeBHryWRCMIaMt4V-TQlTgyUA4ndejEgBGUCUw7rwM-ltDr-do8ry-MRv26qQTpS-iCtvONYc6xZBURPEaTo2Nkfq8HJeFA_g6mMLUBG',
    timeout : 1800,
    lang : 'en',
    site : '6LceKe0SAAAAACFIVHolzCVkrGgSfzFASoOmELIc',
    error_message : '',
    programming_error : '',
    is_incorrect : false,
    rtl : false,
    t1 : 'Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9qcy90aC83ZFZqVVRQN3pmYXh1UnMtNFV3Q19KT0dvbHU4LWdXcXhHTlhNMjRoV1VZLmpz',
    t2 : '',
    t3 : 'NjliZ0lya2VaS3JHpaaU9sbFJuSREF6Sk9KMNZbW9tcjlvcVlEnV5Y3NlWHN2YWt6ZEdleDZQcVkyaForVXJZclVsZGN0ek5rSGZlU3BuNlkrNkE9PQ\x3d\x3d'
};

</p></body></html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# get only text - without `var rechallengeState = {` and `};`
text = soup.find('p').text.strip()[29:-3]

# split to rows, clean row and split row to columns
rows = [x.strip(',').split(':') for x in text.split('\n')]

# clean and convert to dictionary
data = {a.strip():b.strip(" '") for a,b in rows}

print(data['challenge'])
```

result

```
03AHJ_Vuv8ZHJfsjnR3ueIvm89Jfa6oUJ3-kuzA-VcQIaR30A9CZva7lMaBrYlvcGG4cOPCeKXfERQe_u-cMw_8ZVi6CipeJVAYAsrOeBHryWRCMIaMt4V-TQlTgyUA4ndejEgBGUCUw7rwM-ltDr-do8ry-MRv26qQTpS-iCtvONYc6xZBURPEaTo2Nkfq8HJeFA_g6mMLUBG
```